# ScrollViewer within a ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, touch

I want to create an experience on Windows 7 (using touch) where I can have an outer `ScrollViewer` (which is the size of the screen) that can only scroll vertically. Inside that `ScrollViewer` I will have several other `ScrollViewer` controls that only scroll horizontally, like a bookshelf.

I can do this, but the area where I am having trouble is with touch and focus of events. If I pan horizontally, I ONLY want the horizontal `ScrollViewer` that I am touching to scroll, and if I pan vertically, I ONLY want the outer `ScrollViewer` to scroll.

At the moment, (without code intervention), nesting `ScrollViewer` controls means that the horizontal (inner) `ScrollViewer` controls take the touch focus and the outer vertical `ScrollViewer` never seems to fire the scrolling events.

I figure I can use attached events or Preview events to capture the touch movements and fire scrolling methods, but Im not sure on the best way to achieve something like this.

Here is an overview of the XAML I have:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="OutterScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                             ...content...
            </ScrollViewer>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            ...content...
            </ScrollViewer>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer3" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" PanningMode="HorizontalOnly">
            ...content...
            </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wanted the outer one to scroll horizontally and inside I had 3 scrollviewers that I wanted to scroll Vertically. Here is some code:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        Code
    </ScrollViewer>
    ...
</ScrollViewer>
```